# How to get a product's image in Magento?

Tags: magento

I'm running on version 1.3.2.1,
but on my client's server they had Magento 1.3.0
so my previous code to display images for my local copy,

```
echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product)->resize(163, 100);
```

, does not work on the client's installation.

Looking at the results returned by their Magento, version 1.3.0 actually returns a URL although it points to the skin's media folder.

Is there a way to get the absolute image path for the image?
Or should I make changes somewhere else that would tell Magento that the media directory should be on the root?

Comment: my bad, it does not load images from the skin directory
it just so happened that it loads the default no-image-found (on the skin's folder) in case the products' image is not found

Comment: (string)Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($product, 'image');

Answer (score 55):

```
echo $_product->getImageUrl();
```

This method of the Product class should do the trick for you.

Comment: dont forget to add this too: ->addAttributeToSelect('image')

Comment: @HaydenThring you are the saviour!

Comment: @deprecated since 1.1.5

Answer (score 33):

You can try to replace `$this->` by `Mage::` in some cases. You need to convert to string.

In my case i'm using [DirectResize extension](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/direct-resize-2207.html) [(direct link)](http://connect20.magentocommerce.com/community/NetAmbition_DirectResize/1.3/NetAmbition_DirectResize-1.3.tgz), so my code is like this:

```
(string)Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'image')->directResize(150,150,3)
```

The ratio options (3rd param) are :

- none proportional. The image will be resized at the Width and Height values.
- proportional, based on the Width value 2
- proportional, based on the Height value 3
- proportional for the new image can fit in the Width and the Height values. 4
- proportional. The new image will cover an area with the Width and the Height values.

Update: other info and versions [here](http://ext.topmage.com/extensions/e9/3c/NetAmbition_DirectResize/)

---

The common way, **without plugin would be**:

```
(string)Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'image')->resize(150)
```

You can replace 'image' with 'small_image' or 'thumbnail'.

Comment: In your opinion, why 'image' won't work and 'small_image' will work, in my setup? 'image' always display the standard Magento image (but in my products I specified all the three images, base, small and thumb). Until some days ago, 'image' was working, then suddenly stopped. No updates or other back-end changes was made.

Answer (score 13):

I recently needed to do this as well... here's how I got to it:

```
$_product->getMediaGalleryImages()->getItemByColumnValue('label', 'LABEL_NAME')->getUrl();
```

Hope that helps you!

Comment: This was perfect. Handy for getting a specific image (a product banner, say) outside the product view.

Answer (score 8):

Here is the way I've found to load all image data for all products in a collection.  I am not sure at the moment why its needed to switch from Mage::getModel to Mage::helper and reload the product, but it must be done.  I've reverse engineered this code from the magento image soap api, so I'm pretty sure its correct.

I have it set to load products with a vendor code equal to '39' but you could change that to any attribute, or just load all the products, or load whatever collection you want (including the collections in the phtml files showing products currently on the screen!)

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
$collection->addFieldToFilter(array(
    array('attribute'=>'vendor_code','eq'=>'39'),
));

$collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');

foreach ($collection as $product) {

    $prod = Mage::helper('catalog/product')->getProduct($product->getId(), null, null);

    $attributes = $prod->getTypeInstance(true)->getSetAttributes($prod);

    $galleryData = $prod->getData('media_gallery');

    foreach ($galleryData['images'] as &$image) {
        var_dump($image);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 5):

First You need to verify the base, small  and thumbnail image are selected in Magento admin.

**admin->catalog->manage product->product->image**

Then select your image roles(base,small,thumbnail)[image]

Then you call the image using

> echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product,
> 'small_image')->resize(163, 100);

Hope this helps you.

Comment: resize doesnt work , still it shows 210 x 210 image. Tried clearing cache and indexes

Answer (score 5):

```
<img src='.$this->helper('catalog/image')->init($product, 'small_image')->resize(225, 225).' width=\'225\' height=\'225\'/>
```

Answer (score 4):

```
// Let's load the category Model and grab the product collection of that category

$product_collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($categoryId)->getProductCollection();

// Now let's loop through the product collection and print the ID of every product 
foreach($product_collection as $product) {
  // Get the product ID

$product_id = $product->getId();

  // Load the full product model based on the product ID

$full_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product_id);

  // Now that we loaded the full product model, let's access all of it's data

  // Let's get the Product Name

  $product_name = $full_product->getName();

  // Let's get the Product URL path

  $product_url = $full_product->getProductUrl();

  // Let's get the Product Image URL

  $product_image_url = $full_product->getImageUrl();

  // Let's print the product information we gathered and continue onto the next one

 echo $product_name;

  echo $product_image_url;


}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need set image type :small_image or image

```
echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(163, 100);
```

Comment: i replaced my line with that and the problem still persists :(

Comment: i have also the same problem in IE & Chrome.
But works in FF, Safari & Opera

Answer (score 3):

If you have the product collection object like:

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
```

Now you can get product sku using `$_product->getSku()` if you can't get image path with

```
echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product,'small_image')->resize(135);
```

Or

```
$_product->getImageUrl();
```

Then you can add a little code

```
$productModel = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
$_prod = $productModel->loadByAttribute('sku', $_product->getSku()); 
$_prod->getImageUrl();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$model = Mage::getModel('catalog/product'); //getting product model
$_products = $model->getCollection(); //getting product object for particular product id
foreach($_products as $_product) { ?>
    <a href = '<?php echo $model->load($_product->getData("entity_id"))->getUrl_path(); ?>'> <img src= '<?php echo $model->load($_product->getData("entity_id"))->getImageUrl();  ?>' width="75px" height="75px"/></a>
     <?php echo "<br/>".$model->load($_product->getData("entity_id"))->getPrice()."<br/>". $model->load($_product->getData("entity_id"))->getSpecial_price()."<br/>".$model->load($_product->getData("entity_id"))->getName()?>
<?php
```

Answer (score 1):

get product images in magento using product id

```
    $product_id = $_POST['product_id'];
    $storeId    = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();
    $loadpro    = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product_id);

    $mediaApi      =  Mage::getModel("catalog/product_attribute_media_api");
    $mediaApiItems = $mediaApi->items($loadpro->getId());
    foreach ($mediaApiItems as $item) {
            //for getting existing Images
            echo $item['file'];
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(string)Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($product, 'image');
```

this will give you image url, even if image hosted on CDN.

Comment: The above no longer works in Magento 1.9.3.8, you need one of:
(string)Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($product, small_'image') OR (string)Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($product, 'detail_image');

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php echo Mage::getModel('catalog/product_media_config')->getMediaUrl($_product->getImage()); ?>
```

This code retrieves the media URL for the product image directly. Please replace $_product->getImage() with the appropriate method or attribute for your specific use case.

If you want to customize the image size, you can append the resize method to the above code:

```
<?php echo Mage::getModel('catalog/product_media_config')->getMediaUrl($_product->getImage())->resize(163, 100); ?>
```

If your code is still not working, ensure that the product actually has an image set. If not, you might want to check the product in the Magento admin panel and make sure an image is associated with it.

If you're having issues with the image paths and URLs, it's also worth checking the Magento configuration settings related to media URLs. You can find these settings in the Magento Admin Panel under System > Configuration > Web > Unsecure and Secure.

Make sure the "Base Media URL" is set correctly. It should point to the media folder in your Magento installation.

If none of these solutions work, you may need to check for any customizations or extensions that might be affecting the image paths in the client's Magento installation.