# magento same category products thumbnails

Tags: php, magento, thumbnails, product

I have 3 products in the same categoy
I'm trying to display same category products thumbnails in magento `catalog/product/view.phtml`

```
<?php
    $productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($cat_id)
         ->getProductCollection()
         ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
         ->addAttributeToFilter('status', 1);

    $prodIds = $productCollection->getAllIds();

    $prod_siblings = array();
    foreach($prodIds as $productId) 
    {
        $prod =  Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);
        $prod_siblings[] = array(
            'url' => $prod->getProductUrl(),
            'name' => $prod->getName(),
            'image' => $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($prod, 'thumbnail')->constrainOnly(TRUE)->keepAspectRatio(TRUE)->keepFrame(FALSE)->resize(75)
            );
    }
?>
```

with this code, the 3 `$prod_siblings` have their own name and url (stored in the array), but they are all sharing the same image (the image of the last created product).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it !

found my answer here : [How to get a product's image in Magento?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2474117/how-to-get-a-products-image-in-magento)

used `(string)Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($prod, 'thumbnail')...`

instead of `$this->helper('catalog/image')->init($prod, 'thumbnail')...`

Answer (score 0):

Try storing product details in an array n den whole arrays in your `$prod_siblings`. This will look like this:

```
?php
$productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($cat_id)
     ->getProductCollection()
     ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
     ->addAttributeToFilter('status', 1);

$prodIds = $productCollection->getAllIds();

$prod_siblings = array();
foreach($prodIds as $productId) 
{
    $prod =  Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);
    $product_detail[] = array(
        'url' => $prod->getProductUrl(),
        'name' => $prod->getName(),
        'image' => $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($prod, 'thumbnail')->constrainOnly(TRUE)->keepAspectRatio(TRUE)->keepFrame(FALSE)->resize(75)
        );  array_push($prod_siblings,$product_detail[]);
}?>
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Put $product_detail = array() instead of $product_detail[] = array() and array_push($prod_siblings,$product_detail); instead of array_push($prod_siblings,$product_detail[]);try..

Comment: i've found the solution, see my answer, thanks for your help :)