# Get Product Image from Media Gallery by Image Label on Magento

Tags: php, image, magento, gallery, product

I'm a bit stuck with this one. I've uploaded images on our Magento and they do not belong in "image, small_image, thumbnail" labels. They have their own labels in the Media Gallery, which is "Back".

I would like to use this "Back" image as a hover on our product listing page (category page). I've tried using:

```
<?php echo $_product->getMediaGalleryImages()->getItemByColumnValue('label', 'Back')->getUrl();?>
```

To get the URL of the image and use

```
<img>
```

to show it. It gives me an error where it only shows one product and it gets messed up.

I've tried this as well, and gives me a different error, where it does show the back of the image when I hover, BUT it only shows one product and that's it (there is usually 1500+ in the category itself)

```
<?php echo Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getId())->getMediaGalleryImages()->getItemByColumnValue('label','Back')->getUrl(); ?>
```

I'm not well versed in PHP as much as I should be, so maybe the code is wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7448017/763468

Comment: Looked at that before and unfortunately that post did not help me :(

Comment: What is your error? Post more of your categories code.

Comment: Sorry - pretty late reply. No complete answer really.. but here is what I did.

I eventually just had to create a media gallery attribute and just linked it from there. I basically had to back track because I now I bunch of missing images but.. I couldn't find a way to link it and just gave up. :(

Comment: oops, couldn't edit my last post beyond 5 mins.

*continued


If anyone has this same issue, another option would just to create a media gallery attribute and link it with :

'<?php echo $this->helper('adaptiveResize/image')->init($_product, 'hover_image')->adaptiveResize(225, 285); ?>'