# external Url is use for product list in magento

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.8

I am using magento 1.8.1 and i want to use image url for all the product , instead of upload image in media folder.

can you please tell me where i have to change the code for this or how it is possible?

Comment: You should post your code if you want someone tells you _where to change your code_

Comment: @il_raffa I think his problem is that he wants to find the file where that code is located, which specifies the images folder.

Comment: @sumanpathak This seems to have some clues but is for older version of Magento http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2474117/how-to-get-a-products-image-in-magento - it might show up how to use an alternative image location rather than catalogue/image.